# VMware Socket/Core allocation for SQL Server 2016

Tags: vmware

I am requesting a 16 vCPU 256GB RAM VM (Windows 2012|Host ESX 5.5) from our infrastructure team. However, my infrastructure team would like to know how the VM should be setup. What would be the ideal socket/core setup for this VM?

16 socket x 1 core |
2 socket x 8 core  |
4 socket x 4 core

Looking at this blog post it would seem 16 socket to 1 core may be the best setup: https://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2013/10/does-corespersocket-affect-performance.html

Can anyone offer and guidance or thoughts?

Comment: Need to know how the host is configured. You don't want to create a wide VM.

Comment: Hi Tara, thanks for the response. What would I ask our infrastructure team specifically? I know the VM Host resides on a BL460 with 2 physical cores.

Comment: How are you licensed? What version is it? Is it core or socket based?

Comment: Also what will be the memory configuration? You might want to ask about numa

Comment: I meant to say 2 socket BL460. SQL Server is licensed by the core. I am unsure about vmWare

Comment: Are you using Enterprise?

Comment: VM: Windows 2012R2 Standard | 16 vCPU | 256GB RAM | SQL Server 2016 SP1 Enterprise Edition

Comment: Per the article you link to: `ensure you mirror physical server’s NUMA topology`.  Start with mimicking the NUMA configuration of the physical processer.  If it gets you to a core count of 16 (which looks to be your target), I would say that's your best base configuration.  Obviously if testing proves the configuration needs adjustment, do so as it's one of the major benefits of running on top of a VM.

Comment: Have a good look at what else is running on the same host. Ive experienced problems with having different sized VMs on the same hosts.

Answer (score 1):

I found another blog post discussing this same question:

https://blogs.vmware.com/performance/2017/03/virtual-machine-vcpu-and-vnuma-rightsizing-rules-of-thumb.html

I'll likely need to ask for another VM for testing different configurations, but I think we're going to start with 2 Socket | 8 Core configuration.